# Let $f:S^n\to S^n$ be continuous. Can the Image of An Open Set Under $f$ Have Non-Empty Interior?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, spheres

Let $f:S^n\to S^n$ be a continuous map.
Let $x\in S^n$ and $y=f(x)$.
Assume that there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $S^n$ such that no element of $U-\{x\}$ maps to $y$.

> **Question.** Can the interior of $f(U)$ be empty?

**Motivation.** (I made an error in defining the map $\bar f$ (see below), so you may skip this part. Thanks to @EricWofsey for pointing out the mistake).

If the answer to the above question is no, then we can attempt to define the local degree of $f$ in a geometric way.

For then we can do the following: Assume that $U$ is "nice". That is, $U$ is the intersection of $S^n$ with a small ball $B(x, \varepsilon)\subseteq \mathbf R^{n+1}$. Thus $S^n/(S^n-U)$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$.

Now let $V$ be a "nice" neighborhood of $y$ contained in $f(U)$.
We get a map 
$$\bar f: S^n/(S^n-U)\to S^n/(S^n-V)$$
induced from $f$.
Both the domain and target spaces of $\bar f$ are homeomorphic to $S^n$ so we can talk about the degree of $\bar f$ (provided we have a scheme to consistently choose generators of $H_n(S^n/(S^n-U))$ and $H_n(S^n/(S^n-V))$).

Comment: Why not $Id:S^n \to S^n$, any $x \in S^n$ and $U=S^n$ ?

Comment: @Nitrogen Sorry. I meant "can the interior of $f(U)$ be *empty*?".

Comment: Having $V$ be contained in $f(U)$ is neither necessary nor sufficient to define your $\bar{f}$.  What you need is for $f(\partial U)$ to be disjoint from $V$.

Comment: @EricWofsey You are right. I made a mistake. I will soon post a revised form specifically about geometric interpretation of local degree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this can happen.  For instance, consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $f(x)=(\|x\|,0,\dots,0)$ (where $\|x\|$ is the Euclidean norm), which extends continuously to a map $S^n\to S^n$ between the one-point compactifications.  For $x=(0,0,0,\dots,0)$, there are no preimages of $f(x)$ besides $x$, but $f(S^n)$ has empty interior if $n>1$.

(For $n=1$, it is easy to see that $f(U)$ must have nonempty interior as long as $f$ is not constant on $U$.)

Comment: It seems to me that every point in $S^n$ will get mapped to the same point by this $f$. Also, $x = \vec 0 $ is not a point of $S^n$ to me. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I am considering $S^n=\mathbb{R}^n\cup\{\infty\}$, not $S^{n-1}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now! +1

Comment: Is this equivalent to the mapping in a sphere which takes every point in the same horizontal plane to a given meridian?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to picture it.  But the details of the global picture aren't important, since the question is just about the local behavior near $x$ (so you might as well visualize things as being in $\mathbb{R}^n$, not $S^n$).